# Algebraic topology : Adam's Theorem

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology

In class, i learn Adam's Theorem.

Which states the tangent bundle on $S^n$ is trivial only $n=1,3,7$.

I arise some question about $n$. Why $n=1,3,7$ are so special?

The professor give simple explanation about $n=1$.

$i.e$ for $n=1$, we can introduce complex coordinate such that $S^1$ contain $\mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{C}$.

Comment: You forgot $n=0$.

Comment: I am afraid that this is very far from trivial. This is the Milnor's Theorem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a very difficult problem that thwarted algebraic topologists a long time. The reference is:

> Adams, J. F. *On the non-existence of elements of Hopf invariant one*. Ann. of Math. (2), 1960, 72, 20-104

That you can find on [JSTOR](http://jstor.org/stable/1970147). Adams provides this helpful diagram:

[image]

In particular it has also to do with the existence of a [divison algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algebra) structure on $\mathbb{R}^n$, on the existence of [Hopf invariant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hopf_invariant) one maps...

The proof in that paper goes through [secondary cohomology operations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secondary_cohomology_operation). The idea itself is very simple (once you know it), it's the details that are insanely difficult. For example it's easy to see with ordinary [Steenrod squares](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steenrod_algebra) that $n$ has to be a power of $2$ for $S^{n-1}$ to have a trivial tangent bundle, thanks to the fact that the four conclusions in this theorem are equivalent for a given $n$:

[image]

It's because $\operatorname{Sq}^n$ is decomposable in terms of $\operatorname{Sq}^i \operatorname{Sq}^j$ with $i,j < n$ when $n$ is not a power of $2$. To prove that $n$ must be one of $1,2,4,8$, you go through secondary operations and apply the same idea (try to decompose $\operatorname{Sq}^n$ with lower terms).

---

Note that the converse is much simpler: if $n=1,2,4,8$ it's very easy to show that $S^{n-1}$ has trivial tangent bundle. The answer comes from the real line $\mathbb{R}$, the complex plane $\mathbb{C}$, the quaternions $\mathbb{H}$ and the octonions $\mathbb{O}$; they're all division algebras, and $S^{n-1}$ is the unit sphere of these division algebras. It's then easy to show that this imply what we want.

Comment: Amazing!, It seems i have to study more harder.